# logging into website using vba - un and pw dissapear when clicking submit

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to write a macro that will simply log in to [this](https://uk.webuy.com/) website.

I've done some web-scraping before and was always able to successfully do similar stuff on other websites, but I can't figure out this one.

I've tried so many things, last attempt (being very desperate!) was to enter username and password, and call all possible scripts and fire all possible events, see code below. Please ignore how I did/named certain things (like eventsArray for a collection etc) - i kept trying new things and changing the code many times, it's all temporary.

```
    Dim eventsArray As New Collection
    eventsArray.Add "abort"
    eventsArray.Add "afterprint"
    eventsArray.Add "animationend"
    eventsArray.Add "animationiteration"
    eventsArray.Add "animationstart"
    eventsArray.Add "beforeprint"
    eventsArray.Add "beforeunload"
    eventsArray.Add "blur"
    eventsArray.Add "canplay"
    eventsArray.Add "canplaythrough"
    eventsArray.Add "change"
    eventsArray.Add "click"
    eventsArray.Add "contextmenu"
    eventsArray.Add "copy"
    eventsArray.Add "cut"
    eventsArray.Add "dblclick"
    eventsArray.Add "drag"
    eventsArray.Add "dragend"
    eventsArray.Add "dragenter"
    eventsArray.Add "dragleave"
    eventsArray.Add "dragover"
    eventsArray.Add "dragstart"
    eventsArray.Add "drop"
    eventsArray.Add "durationchange"
    eventsArray.Add "ended"
    eventsArray.Add "error"
    eventsArray.Add "focus"
    eventsArray.Add "focusin"
    eventsArray.Add "focusout"
    eventsArray.Add "fullscreenchange"
    eventsArray.Add "fullscreenerror"
    eventsArray.Add "hashchange"
    eventsArray.Add "input"
    eventsArray.Add "invalid"
    eventsArray.Add "keydown"
    eventsArray.Add "keypress"
    eventsArray.Add "keyup"
    eventsArray.Add "load"
    eventsArray.Add "loadeddata"
    eventsArray.Add "loadedmetadata"
    eventsArray.Add "loadstart"
    eventsArray.Add "message"
    eventsArray.Add "mousedown"
    eventsArray.Add "mouseenter"
    eventsArray.Add "mouseleave"
    eventsArray.Add "mousemove"
    eventsArray.Add "mouseover"
    eventsArray.Add "mouseout"
    eventsArray.Add "mouseup"
    eventsArray.Add "mousewheel"
    eventsArray.Add "offline"
    eventsArray.Add "online"
    eventsArray.Add "open"
    eventsArray.Add "pagehide"
    eventsArray.Add "pageshow"
    eventsArray.Add "paste"
    eventsArray.Add "pause"
    eventsArray.Add "play"
    eventsArray.Add "playing"
    eventsArray.Add "popstate"
    eventsArray.Add "progress"
    eventsArray.Add "ratechange"
    eventsArray.Add "resize"
    eventsArray.Add "reset"
    eventsArray.Add "scroll"
    eventsArray.Add "search"
    eventsArray.Add "seeked"
    eventsArray.Add "seeking"
    eventsArray.Add "select"
    eventsArray.Add "show"
    eventsArray.Add "stalled"
    eventsArray.Add "storage"
    eventsArray.Add "submit"
    eventsArray.Add "suspend"
    eventsArray.Add "timeupdate"
    eventsArray.Add "toggle"
    eventsArray.Add "touchcancel"
    eventsArray.Add "touchend"
    eventsArray.Add "touchmove"
    eventsArray.Add "touchstart"
    eventsArray.Add "transitionend"
    eventsArray.Add "unload"
    eventsArray.Add "volumechange"
    eventsArray.Add "waiting"
    eventsArray.Add "wheel"

    'set un and pw obj
    Set user = IE.Document.all.user
    Set pass = IE.Document.all.pass

    'enter un and pw
    user.Value = "test@test.com"
    pass.Value = "test123"

    'for each element
    For Each ele In Array(user, pass)
        'fire all poss events
        For Each fEvent In eventsArray
            On Error Resume Next
            ele.FireEvent ("on" & fEvent)
            ele.FireEvent (fEvent)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    Next

    'exec all scripts availible in document
    For Each scr In IE.Document.Scripts
        On Error Resume Next
        Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript(scr.src, "JavaScript")
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    'sign in
    IE.Document.getElementById("loginLink").Click
```

What happens is after clicking sign in it returns "You are missing email address blahblah" and both values disappear. If I amend one of these fields manually before submitting, the other value disappears.

I've tried some random things like adding event listeners, clicking, focusing and what not, even tried to do all these things after entering each character for both username and password. I admit I just blindly tried all these things in a hope that something's gonna work, obviously had no success and I don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated!

/edit:
I achieved desired result by using sendkeys (space + backspace in each field) however I don't want to do it this way. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: Once you fill in the credentials to log in manually, how do you figure that you have logged in, meaning do you see your profile name in the new page or something?

Comment: The "customer login" box disappears, and "My Account" appears in place of "Sign In" on top of the page.

Comment: I can see both of them `My Account` and `Sign In` when I run my macro. So, your information is not accurate.

Comment: Before you log in, the first 2 buttons on top of the page are "Sign in" and "Sign up". To log in, click "Sign In" and this should open a "Customer Log In" box to enter credentials. Once you successfully log in, the box will disappear, "Sign In" button will disappear and "Sign up" will change to "My Account".

Comment: Alternatively, you can navigate to "https://uk.webuy.com/user/myaccount" - if you're logged in, you'll see "Order Tracking" and other options, otherwise it'll open a box and throw "Sorry, something went wrong with that. Please try again in a few seconds".

Comment: I made a test with this code https://textuploader.com/157nx and got similar results like yours. Looks like that site cause some issue. I checked with my own web page which works correctly with the same code. So with this testing result, We can say that there is not issue with VBA code.

Comment: I guess there must some script that is triggered by manual input, which could be programmatically called, but I can't find it. There must be a way, I'm just not good enough with DOM explorer and when it comes to more complex stuff, like this, I struggle.

Comment: If you check the source code of the textbox than you can notice 2 attributes. (1) aria-required (2) aria-invalid. I am suspecting that these attributes and some other code causing this issue.

Comment: I've tried setting these attributes to False, no success. What I noticed however is, when populating field manually, dynamic script appears in DOM. Hence why it's not executed when I'm calling all available scripts. I'm not sure how to call it (where to get the name of it from as it's different every time, I suppose it's un/pw encryption). It looks like manual click fires it, but neither '.click' or 'onclick' event works!

Comment: we can see that site not allow the automation to get logged in. So first try to login the site manually and than try to use automation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [selenium basic vba](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) (install and ensure latest chromedriver is in the selenium folder) and vbe > tools > references > add selenium type library reference. It's much cleaner.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Login()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get "https://uk.webuy.com/"

        .FindElementByCss("#signIn").Click
        .FindElementByCss("#user").SendKeys "abc@aol.com"
        .FindElementByCss("#pass").SendKeys "password"
        .FindElementByCss("#loginLink").Click

        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr for advise, I would however prefer not to use selenium, so that it will work on different stations, and it can be used as vbscript. Also I would avoid SendKeys at all cost (unless it's a different thing in selenium?).

Comment: sendkeys is fine with selenium in my opinion. Very reliable.

Comment: Is it any different to the SendKeys I know, meaning it will fail if the window isn't active for example?

Comment: What are you going to be doing that would change the orientation? You could flick tabs and it would still send to the right page. It sends to the element.

Comment: I'll have a proper look at IE solution maybe later today.

Comment: I want it to run in the background while I'm doing other things as it does some stuff after logging in. I will run it off windows task scheduler so most likely I will save it as vbscript rather than excel macro, but thats not necessary, although it's another reason why I don't want to use SendKeys and selenium. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: yeah... you can run headless and that can can be run from vbscript  via task scheduler. In fact, you could avoid vba per se and just write the whole thing in vbscript as selenium supports that. But yes, requires users to have the appropriate set-up.

Comment: Avoiding VBA is a great bonus but is not necessary since I enter some data on spreadsheet anyway (order numbers and stuff for my record). In any case, I will be able to translate it to VBS anyway as it's almost the same thing. Selenium however, even though it sounds fantastic, needs to be avoided for now!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Sub cexLogIn()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim reqBody As String
Dim reqURL As String
Dim respHeaders As String
Dim resp As String
reqURL = "https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/members/login"
reqBody = "{""password"":""PASSWORD"",""email"":""EMAIL@EMAIL.COM""}" 'use your credentials
With req
    .Open "POST", reqURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Host", "wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
    .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://uk.webuy.com/"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

    .send reqBody
    resp = .responseText
    respHeaders = .getAllResponseHeaders
End With
Debug.Print respHeaders
Debug.Print resp
End Sub
```

Change the caps to match your credentials.

This should normally get you logged in and your session cookie should be returned to you in the response headers. This cookie could probably be attached to any further requests you'd like to make to the website.

I haven't tried it because I don't want to sign up, but you could give it a try and see how it goes.

References: `Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1`